# TCPDF - Pagenumbers not exactly right aligned

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to generate a pdf.

My issue is the following line from the Footer() method:

```
$this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 'T', false, 'R');
```

This is the standard line for inserting the pagenumber in the document's footer but there is a litte space to right in the output. You can see it in example 1 from the website: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_001.pdf

If I insert normal text like this:

```
$this->Cell(0, 10, 'Foobar', 'T', false, 'R');
```

the text is perfectly aligned to the right without any problems.

I digged into the source, it seems to be something with the encoding, but I don't really get the point.. can somebody help?

regards

Answer (score 5):

i solved it like this:

```
$this->Cell(0, 0, $this->getAliasRightShift().$this->PageNo().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 1, 0, 'R');
```

if you have more than 99 pages, you will again have alignment problems! use something else to generate a pdf of your degree thesis! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add page number after generating, no need of aliases.
Do it at the end just before `$pdf->Output(...);`

```
$numPages = $pdf->getNumPages();

for($int=1;$int < $numPages + 1; $int++)
{
    $pdf->setPage($int);
    $pdf->SetY(-15);
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
    $pdf->writeHTML('Page '.$int.'/'.$numPages,true,false,true,false,'R');
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Btw, if you're using auto page break, then you might want to use `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);` inside the `for` loop after `setPage()` to make sure the added content stays on that page. (Since you're probably drawing inside the page margin area, which would otherwise make it go to the next page.)

Answer (score 2):

I have solved using:

```
$txt='Page '.$this->PageNo().' of '.$this->getNumPages()
```

instead of:

```
$txt='Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().' of '.$this->getAliasNbPages()
```

Italian translation and updates at [Isotypelab.org](http://isotypelab.org/tcpdf-come-allineare-correttamente-destra-il-numero-di-pagina)

Comment: This doesn't really work, since it prints "Page 1 of 1" and "Pagen 2 of 2"

Comment: Doesn't work, the solution for me is put this page information to align LEFT :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately TCPDF **align the alias** and **not the final number** that replaces
the alias. Using $this->AliasNbPages('{p}') and $this->AliasNumPAge('{n}') won't help a lot. Extra padding will remain in place.

The only solution is to put page numbers instead of aliases.

[Original bug at SourceForge.net (TCPDF bug tracker)](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3313832&group_id=128076&atid=710532)

Answer (score 1):

As my document is no more than 10 pages I have 2 solutions, give it more WIDTH(260 in my case because I have PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION='L') and align 'R':

```
$this->Cell(260, 6, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().' of '.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, 0, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
```

or two cells with WIDTH=0, align 'C' and second Cell with some spaces:

```
$this->Cell(0, 6, '', 0, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
$this->Cell(0, 6, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().' of '.$this->getAliasNbPages().'        ', 0, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
```

so play with WIDTH and SPACES if you have more than 10 pages.

This aligned page numbers to the right in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is within the **aliases**. These are just pieces of text of which the width is calculated at the time of insertion, and not the time of replacing them with numbers.

So the text-width is calculated for the string (literally) `{np}/{nb}`. And when it is replaced with numbers right at the end `1/9` is smaller than that, whilst `23/109` is larger.

You can replace the NbPages alias used (`setAliasNbPages()`?), with something that reflects the width of `the total number of pages` íf you can estimate how many that will be. And I believe you can directly use the current page number without using an alias so the problem at least doesn't appear for that alias.

Answer (score 0):

getNumPages won't do it.
If you have 3 pages, getNumPages() will result in 1/1, 2/2 and 3/3
getAliasNbPages() will result in 1/3, 2/3 and 3/3
so the problem remains!

Comment: should be posted as a comment, which you will be able to do once you'll have enough rep :-)

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF align the alias instead of the real page number. To align to the right, don't use the alias:

```
$pageNumber = $this->getPage();
$this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$pageNumber, 'T', false, 'R');
```

Unfortunately for the  total number of pages, you have no solution because when your footer code is called, all the pages are not yet inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. My solution is adding the text-width of the alias minus the width of a page number (I'm generating invoices, so it's mostly 1 digit). So this solution is only working for documents with max 9 pages.

```
// this is outputting the wrong margins:
$this->writeHTMLCell(35, 0, 150, $this->GetY(), sprintf(SEITENZAHLEN, $this->PageNo(),$this->getAliasNbPages() ),1,1,false,true,'R',true);
```

Now calculate the text_width of the alias and add it to the cell width

```
$text_width = $this->GetStringWidth( $this->getAliasNbPages() ) - $this->GetStringWidth('2');
$this->writeHTMLCell(35+$text_width, 0, 150, $this->GetY(), sprintf(SEITENZAHLEN, $this->PageNo(),$this->getAliasNbPages() ),1,0,false,true,'R',true);
```

And no it's perfectly aligned :-)

[image: aligned page numbers]

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found was to keep using the alias to get the total amount of pages, but using the alternative "pageNo" method to get the current page.

Then you can "push" the cell that contains the page number a bit to the right in order to place it where you want (if it's aligned to the right side of the page). If you want to keep it centered, the solution will probably be more complex.

If you check the examples provided on the TCPDF website, paying attention to the page numbers, you will see that there are blank spaces after the page number as well, so it's very likely that nobody found a solution yet.

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
$txt='Page '.$this->PageNo().' of '.$this->getNumPages()
```

working for me

Comment: you repeated a not working solution:
This doesn't really work, since it prints "Page 1 of 1" and "Pagen 2 of 2"